# Asymptotic behavior of canonical perturbation theory for the classic anharmonic oscillator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, perturbation-theory, anharmonic-oscillators

What do we know about the asymptotic behavior of the perturbative expansion for the classical anharmonic oscillator?
The Hamiltonian is 
$$
H = \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_0^2 q^2 +\mu q^4
$$ 
and canonical perturbation theory at first or second order is worked out in many text books, see, for example, Jose and Saletan (6.133) and below. The dimensionless parameter of the expansion is 
$$
\epsilon = \frac{4\mu E^0}{m^2\omega_0^4}
$$
where $E^0=\frac{1}{2}m\omega_0^2 q_{\it max}^2$, and I would like to understand the behavior of the perturbed frequency $\omega$ as a function of $\epsilon$.

P.S.: It occurred to me that the question is maybe not that interesting. In the end, the anharmonic oscillator is an integrable system, and the solution can be expressed in terms of elliptic functions. This means that the calculation does not require canonical perturbation theory -- it can presumably be done by expanding out integrals. Given that the motion remains stable for finite $\epsilon$, I would expect that perturbation theory has a finite range of convergence.